# Enter a string to a variable in PHP

Tags: php

how to combine variables with string and generate value

```
<?php
$bun1="home";
$x="1";
$h= "$"."bun".$x;
echo $h;
?>
```

I want print $bun1 with result home, but "1" in $bun1 be variable $x

Comment: <?php
$bun1="home";
$x="1";
$h= '$bun'.$x;
echo $h;
?>

Comment: @hediguzo - please mark one of the answers as accepted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called *variable variables*.

PHP.net has [a whole page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) on it.

```
<?php
$bun1="home";
$x="1";
$h= ${"bun".$x};
echo $h;
?>
```

Thing is though, from a design standpoint, you're almost always doing it wrong if you're using variable variables. Use arrays instead:

```
<?php
$bun[1] = "home";
$x=1;
$h= $bun[$x];
echo $h;
?>
```

If you're just trying to learn, then okay, have at it.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look, You just need to combine them so that you can make the variable name and then use the `$` before that name to make it is a PHP variable.

```
$bun1 = "home";
$x = "1";
$h = ${"bun".$x};
echo $h;
```

You can also do the same thing like this way--

```
$bun1 = "home";
$x = "1";
$h = "bun".$x;
echo $$h; // this is called variable of variable. In `$h` you have only the 'bun1' and when you use a `$` before it it will be the `$bun1` and the value is `home`.
```